# Save Sort Preference to MySQL Using PHP, Drag-and-Drop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using JQuery to provide my users with a re-arrangeable list of items. Like this:

[Image of List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJMNh.jpg)

Here's the simple HTML:

```
      <ul class="sortable">
      <li>Item 1<i class="sorthandle"></i></li>
      <li>Item 2<i class="sorthandle"></i></li>          
      </ul>
```

The drag-and-drop feature works great. The next step is saving the user's sort preference to the database. I plan to add a "priority" column to my database, which will hold an integer representing the user's preferred sort order. My query will then `Order by 'priority' ASC`.

I'm thinking I need to generate an array of the sort order currently displayed on the drag-and-drop screen, then save those values to the database records. But as a JavaScript newbie, I need some help.

**My JavaScript**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    handle: '.handle'
  }).disableSelection();

});
</script>
```

**Generating the drag-and-drop list via PHP:**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $playlistname = $row['name'];
  $id = $row['id'];
  echo "<li>$playlistname<i class='handle fa fa-bars'></i></li>";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this without writing any more JavaScript. PHP worked just  fine!

**PHP - Getting Values**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT name, id FROM playlists WHERE userid = 'XX' AND active = 1 ORDER BY priority ASC";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 ?>
<form action="" method="POST">

<div class="container">
      <ul class="sortable">

        <?php
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ /* FETCH ARRAY */
          $playlistname = $row['name'];
          $id = $row['id'];
          echo "<li>$playlistname<i class='handle fa fa-bars'><input type='hidden' name='sort[]' value='$id' /></i></li>";
          }
        ?>

        </ul>
</div>
<center><button name="submit" id="sortsavebutton" type="SUBMIT" value="submit" action="POST">Save</button></center><br>
</form>
```

**Processing on Save/Submission**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $rearrange = $_POST['sort'];
    $count = count($rearrange);
    $sort = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

        if(!empty($rearrange[$i])){ 

        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$rearrange[$i]); /* ESCAPE STRINGS */
    $priority = $sort++;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE playlists SET priority=? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $priority, $id);
    $stmt->execute();

          } 

    } 

}
```

Comment: Your code is massively vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thanks for taking the advice and improving your code (you wouldn't believe how many people just couldn't be arsed)! you should also mark your answer as accepted to indicate that the problem is solved. I will also keep my answer there, because it shows a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, JavaScript will need the IDs, not just the name. You can simply put them in a data attribute (I also got rid of the unnecessary variable assignments and built the string with concatenation)

```
echo '<li data-id="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '<i class="handle fa fa-bars"></i></li>';
```

You can then extract this data attribute in JavaScript and create an array. You might want to think about when you save the settings. The easiest way would be to provide a button. You could also do it on the [sortable update](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) event (e.g. after "dropping" the element). But that is risky and might overload your server.

To trigger an AJAX POST on button click, put this code within `$(function() {`. It binds a lambda function on the `click` event of the DOM element with the ID `save`, f.ex. `<button id="save">save order</button>`

```
// bind a callback to the button click
$('#save').on('click', function () {
    // array where we store the IDs
    var ids = [];
    // loop through the <li> and extract data-id
    $('.sortable li').each(function() {
        ids.push($(this).data('id'));
    });

    // AJAX POST the array to a PHP script
    $.post('/savescript.php', {'ids[]': ids});
});
```

you can then access the data in `$_POST['ids']`.